# android -how to remove margin from top and bottom of custom actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using a custom actionbar for my application . this is the code :

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setIcon(null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) mCustomView.getParent();
    parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
```

this is the result of this code , I 've margins from top and bottom :

[image]

How can I remove this margin ?

i'm using Theme.AppCompat.Light for my application template .

Comment: Can you provide the xml for your custon actionbar, and also the activity's xml too

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to put the Toolbar layout xml in a separate file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/actionBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp" >
```

Then include it in your main.xml

```
<include layout="@layout/view_action_bar" />
```

Also make sure to : `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"`  this is the main issue for your magins.

Answer (score 0):

In your ActionBar layout file give the android:heigth as match parent for the Parent View. I also had a same issue with it.

Comment: i've set match parent to the parent view but it doesn't work

Comment: @navidjons can you check by setting some minimum height to the parent with android:heigth as match_parent